# Why does my curl request on a redirection return 500 after the 301 redirect?

Tags: curl

I have a redirect set up at the load balancer level. When using CURL, I'm getting a 500 error.  When I request the URL in the browser, everything is successful, and I get a 200.

This is the request that I'm expecting a redirect from http --> https.

```
curl -iL --request POST 'http://example.com/endpoint' --data-raw '{"mydata": "data"}'
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://example.com:443/endpoint

HTTP/2 500 
server: Google Frontend
```

```
curl -v -L --request POST 'http://example.com/endpoint' --data-raw '{"mydata": "data"}'
```

Response:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.example.com port 80 (#0)
> POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> cache: no-cache
> Content-Length: 93
> 
* upload completely sent off: 93 out of 93 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Location: https://www.example.com:443/endpoint
< Content-Length: 269
< Date: Mon, 30 May 2022 21:09:53 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.example.com:443/endpoint'
* Switch from POST to GET
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.example.com (X.X.X.X) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=example.com
*  start date: May  8 17:51:30 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  6 17:51:29 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.example.com" matched cert's "www.example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1D4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
> POST /endpoint HTTP/2
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> cache: no-cache
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 500 
< content-type: application/json
< date: Mon, 30 May 2022 21:09:53 GMT
< server: Google Frontend
< content-length: 110
< via: 1.1 google
< 
* Connection #1 to host www.example.com left intact
```

However, a request to the end URL

```
curl -iL --request POST 'https://example.com/endpoint' --data-raw '{"mydata": "data"}'
```

returns:

```
HTTP/2 200 
server: Google Frontend
```

I've checked in the logs, and the 500 is actually returned from the application layer.
I'm not sure why the first curl request fails, but the second is successful.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add `-v`, in stead of `-i`, and then add the headers that are sent and returned to your question?

Comment: @Luuk thank you - I have updated my question to contain the -v response.

Comment: It might be the "Switch from POST to GET". Details are here [How to work around POST being changed to GET on 302 redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548341/how-to-work-around-post-being-changed-to-get-on-302-redirect)

Comment: @Luuk that's a great point - I'm not sure how to solve that from the link though.

Comment: I do not know how to solve your problem, But this link might help : [docs curl](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--post301)  (If only to find more reference points to find out why this happens)